# Custom ListView OnItemClickListener not working on the some items in the same row

Tags: android, listview

I have my `OnItemClickListener` like this

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Response on click");
        //get object from custom adapter with position
        //calling function
    }
});
```

and my list item view has `Button`, `ImageView`, and `TextView`.

When I clicked on the `Button`, NO RESPONSE.

When I clicked on the `TexView` and `ImageView`, `OnItemClick` is called.

Why this happen ? Because i want the handle event when user clicked on the button !

Comment: did you tried setting the OnClickListener to your button in your adapter, instead of using the list's OnItemClickListener?

Comment: ya tried, it works, but i want the data of that particular clicked list row. Any ideas ?

Comment: do not reuse the OnClickListener for the button, instead of this create a new one for every list item in the adapter, and use the position to get the item you are clicking on...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `onClickListener` to the button. This example show you how to do it and how to get the data from the adapter when you click the button:

```
public class ListViewExampleActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = ListViewExampleActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listviewexampleactivity);

        String[] values = new String[]{"LOLLIPOP_MR1", "LOLLIPOP", 
                                        "KITKAT_WATCH", "KITKAT", "JELLY_BEAN_MR2", "JELLY_BEAN_MR1", 
                                        "JELLY_BEAN", "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1", "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH", 
                                        "HONEYCOMB_MR2", "HONEYCOMB_MR1", "HONEYCOMB", "GINGERBREAD_MR1", 
                                        "GINGERBREAD", "FROYO", "ECLAIR_MR1", "ECLAIR_0_1", "ECLAIR", "DONUT", 
                                        "CUPCAKE", "BASE_1_1", "BASE"};

        final CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, values);

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ListView onItemClick " + adapter.getItem(position));
            }
        });
    }

    private void onButtonClick(String value) {
        //do your stuff with value
    }

    public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_view_item, values);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            textView.setText(getItem(position));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark);

            Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String value = getItem(position);
                    onButtonClick(value);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Button onClick " + value);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

list_view_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_dark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Test me!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi there, how can i pass the "value" variable in the adapter to the to the activity ?

Comment: You can use the method `onButtonClick` that I just added. Let me know.